# custom prolog to each function in visual studio c

Tags: c, performance, visual-studio

I have a large code base that i want to perform performance tests and add diagnostics. i wanted to know if there's a way to add a function call as prolog and epilogue to all functions in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't have the resources to write your own profiler, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here. You can instrument your functions manually by adding a prolog and epilog macro as the first and last line of each function in your code, then define the macros as desired. I suspect that what you're really after is recommendations for a commercial performance profiling tool. [There are many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools), but generic "what's the best profiler" type questions and answers are frowned upon here.